# how to resolve java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap, set

I first had the following code

with the following error message

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
        at ca.on.oicr.pinery.lims.gsle.GsleClient.getOrders(GsleClient.java:720)
```

Where line 720 is the second for loop.

I got the answer that I am adding to orders inside a loop that's looping over the elements of orders, that's what causes the exception. Don't modify a collection you're looping over inside the loop. Likewise with samples.

So I re-did this method but I get the following error message:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:794)
    at ca.on.oicr.pinery.lims.gsle.GsleClient.getOrders(GsleClient.java:730)
```

Where line 730 is Set samples = sampleOrderMap.get(it.next().getId()) in my following code

How would I fix this error message, and will this new method have the same functionality of my original method that did not work, I feel that having all these loops and conditional statements will cause it to not work.

Comment: What is the meaning of putting first part here either, which you know the answer ?

Comment: Wanted to show my work and what i am trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code fragement:

```
 while (it.hasNext()) {
 if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((it.next().getId()))) { // calling it.next()
    if (it.next().getId() != null) { // again calling it.next() ?
       Set<OrderSample> samples = sampleOrderMap.get(it.next().getId()); //again calling 
       for (OrderSample orderSample : samples) {
          Set<Attribute> attributes = attributeOrderMap.get(orderSample.getId());

 ////............ your code
```

You are consecutively calling `it.next()`  upon each call of `iterator.next()`, the iterator advances by one element by returning it. Though i am not sure what object `it.next()` is returning, but you can assign it to a Object of the collection type and use it inside the `while` loop as follows:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Order order = (Order)it.next();  // if Order is your list's type
     if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((order.getId()))) {
        if (order.getId() != null) {
           Set<OrderSample> samples = sampleOrderMap.get(order.getId());
           for (OrderSample orderSample : samples) {
              Set<Attribute> attributes = attributeOrderMap.get(orderSample.getId());
```

Comment: thats why i made the new method that i posted near the bottom of it to take care of that issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `it` is an `Iterator`. (I say that because you did not post the entire source code needed to reproduce this, which you should really do in the future.)

So each time you call `it.next()` you are advancing that iterator. You are calling `it.next()` three times in the first four lines. So if there's only one item left in the `Iterator`, the initial call to `it.hasNext()` will return true but you'll only be able to call `it.next()` once more before running out of items.

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    OrderSample nextSample = it.next();
    // blah blah blah
    // use nextSample instead of it.next() in each subsequence instance.
}
```